# Deleting 1,000s of spam comments

Tags: comments, spam

We are using LowNoSpam and it is working well. Very few spam comments get through. However the settings flagged them as spam and kept them closed. The person who was reviewing these didn't do that since November and since then spam bots have been having a blast. It now has 35,984 spam comments.

We have changed some settings (must be logged in to leave a comment) but we do want to purge the ~36,000 spam comments. There may be a few legit comments in there, but they are ok with just letting them get deleted.

My idea is to go into the database and delete all comments with a status of "c" in the table "exp_comments". I did this on my local db and it seems to work. However I've also tried some database shortcuts that didn't work out so well (creating custom member fields via the db) because there are links to this data elsewhere.

Is there anything else I need to do other than delete the "c" comments in exp_comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is all you need to do - `exp_comments` has no other dependencies when it comes to "closed" comments.

If you were deleting "open" comments, you'd want to recount the site's statistics afterwards (as `exp_channel_titles` has a `comment_total` column).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, as well as the comment about "open" comments. I may need to do that at some point and I would not have thought about that.